# Two definations of the dynkin system.

Tags: real-analysis

In [this article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system), there are two definitions of the Dynkin system.

I want to prove they are equivalent.

How to use the second definition to prove the second item in the first definition?

Comment: Can you include the definitions here?

Comment: @Travis,thanks,the problem is already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A, B \in D$ such that $A \subseteq B$.  Using the second property, $B^c \in D$.  $B^c$ is disjoint from $A$, so $A \cup B^c \in D$ from property 3.  Do you see what to do next?